# Question about required rigour in mappings proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, alternative-proof

I was just working on some intro problems from an algebra textbook, and one of the proofs I had seemed to make sense to me, but when I compared it to a solution given online, it was seemingly very different and mine seemed to be somewhat of a weak argument. So I am looking for any insight on this, and maybe it will also serve to give me a better understanding of constructing proofs in general.

The question was,

- If $S$ any set, prove that it is impossible to find a mapping of $S$ onto $S^{*}$.
  (where S* represents the set of all subsets of $S$, i.e. the power set).

Well, what I had wrote was,

From previous proofs we know that if $|S|=n$ then $|S^{*}|=2^{n}$

and in order for some mapping $\sigma:S \to S^{*}$ to be onto, we would require that for any $s^{*} \in S$, we can find some $s \in S$ such that $s \sigma= s^{*}$.

Consider the case that $n=0$, then clearly we cannot choose some $s \in S$ to map to any $s^{*} \in S^{*}$ regardless so it is non issue.

And for any $n \gt 0$, we have that $|S^{*}| \gt |S|$ so it cannot be that we can maintain a valid mapping while satisfying the onto property as it would require some elements in S to be mapped to more then one element in S*.

Does this make sense? And if not, what parts are not good about it?

The answer given, was via contradiction, and basically said let f be  any mapping, and showing that f is not onto by constructing an element in S* that is not in the image of any s in S. Which of course seems very nice and valid, but I am trying to understand if one is much more correct/valid etc.

Thanks all for any help/input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second proof, known as the technique of *diagonalization*, also works when $S$ is infinite.

Comment: Thank you , I will check this out . What about the first technique ?

Comment: The first technique only works for finite $S$.